OpenVPN client with webserver
I have the following scenario:
Windows PC with OpenVPN client installed and it connects succesfully. On same machine I have installed webserver listening on 5001 (HTTPS). Internet access from PC is done via Teltonika router.
Its like this: PC (opvn;webserver) <-> router <-> openvpn server
I dont have access to OpenVPN provider to do any modifications except that OpenVPN provider generates urls which I can use to access my webserver. There is a possibility to assign port for vpn client devices access when links are generated.
Currently OpenVPN connects, but I cant ping local vpn gw nor I can access webserver.
Unfortunately I have only basic network knowledge. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!
